# SageMath x-axis division of plotted function

Tags: math, plot, sage, pi

i am looking for a way to display just special values on the x-axis in a plot of a function on SageMath. (e.g. 0, pi/4, pi/2, 3pi/4, pi, ...)

Any suggestions?

Comment: IIUC, SageMath is just using `matplotlib` under the hood. So now you have two problems: (1) figure out how to get `matplotlib` to render ticks and tick labels at the points of your choice (which I think should be fairly easy, and just a web search away), and (2) figure out how to get through the SageMath layer. I have no idea how easy or hard (2) is, but maybe it's a question for the SageMath mailing lists once you figure out the solution to problem 1.

Comment: For the `matplotlib` part, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SageMath plotting documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html)
has examples of using `ticks` and `tick_formatter`.

They allow plots like the following:

```py
sage: ticks = [pi/6, sorted({sin(a) for a in [0, pi/6 .. 2*pi]})]
sage: p = plot(sin, 0, 2*pi, ticks=ticks, tick_formatter=pi)
sage: p
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
```

[image: The sine function graph plotted with SageMath with pi-based labels on the x-axis]

To save the plot:

```py
sage: p.save('sine_function_plot.png', figsize=5)
```